# Subtracting days from variable in date and time

Tags: python

I need to subtract 1 day from the current date and time?  How would i do that?
Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
date = (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print(date)
```

Say the date is (2021-10-3) i need the time variable to be set to something like (2021-10-2) Changing the day by -1 day!

Comment: have you tried `now - timedelta(days=1)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
yesterday = now - timedelta(days=1)
date = (yesterday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
print(date)
```

Find more about timedelta [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)